# emberJS squashing nwJS require() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, node-webkit

I have a nwjs application that points to a web address that contains an ember application. Inside the ember application i need to get access to the node context to see what OS the user is running in order to do an update check.  I do that in an initializer like so.

```
require('os')
```

Unfortunately i get this:

```
Error: Could not find module `os` imported from `(require)`
```

It appears that ember's require() method is squashing the one set by nwjs. I can confirm this by changing the nwjs window to point to google.com, setting the "node-remote" to "*", and then trying to run the require('os') command again. In this instance the module is resolved perfectly.

Ember's code reflects this. 
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/27862a18b8773e57c52dbc7141b1f92a505f16ff/packages/loader/lib/index.js

Is there another way to access the proper require() or do i need to create a "node-main" file and just do a

```
window.nodeRequire = require
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a hold of the correct require from the mainModule like so.

`process.mainModule.require('os')`